# Trying to use Delta Tables results in "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/UnresolvedLeafNode"

Tags: apache-spark, delta-live-tables

I am trying to use `Delta-Tables` in a standalone spark local environment.

1a. The `delta-spark` package was installed:

```bash
pip install -y io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.1.0
```

1b.  I am on spark 3.5.0:

```
 $pip show pyspark
Name: pyspark
Version: 3.5.0
Summary: Apache Spark Python API
Home-page: https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/python
Author: Spark Developers
Author-email: dev@spark.apache.org
License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Location: /Users/stephenboesch/python/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: py4j
Required-by: delta-spark
```

2. let's run `spark-sql` with it:

```bash
spark-sql --packages io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.1.0 
--conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delaSparkSessionExtension" 
--conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
```

2a. Seems to be a library/versioning issue?

```
The jars for the packages stored in: /Users/stephenboesch/.ivy2/jars
io.delta#delta-spark_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-e5b920a9-e134-4aa7-9002-64d01564dc90;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found io.delta#delta-spark_2.12;3.1.0 in central
    found io.delta#delta-storage;3.1.0 in central
    found org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.9.3 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 268ms :: artifacts dl 24ms
    :: modules in use:
    io.delta#delta-spark_2.12;3.1.0 from central in [default]
    io.delta#delta-storage;3.1.0 from central in [default]
    org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.9.3 from central in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   3   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   3   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-e5b920a9-e134-4aa7-9002-64d01564dc90
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 3 already retrieved (0kB/23ms)
24/02/23 12:57:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
24/02/23 12:57:05 WARN SparkSession: Cannot use io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension to configure session extensions.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/UnresolvedLeafNode
```

3. Can we create a table?

```sql
CREATE TABLE delta.`/tmp/delta-table` 
USING DELTA AS SELECT col1 as id 
FROM VALUES 0,1,2,3,4;
```

4. Maybe not?

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.9.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.8ANTLR Runtime version 4.9.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.8ANTLR Tool version 4.9.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.8ANTLR Runtime version 4.9.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.824/02/23 12:45:58 ERROR SparkSQLDriver: Failed in [CREATE TABLE delta.`/tmp/delta-table` USING DELTA AS SELECT col1 as id FROM VALUES 0,1,2,3,4]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/UnresolvedLeafNode
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
  ..
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedLeafNode
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
    ... 95 more
```

So then what is correct set of incantations for delta-tables?

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade your spark version to 3.5.x

Comment: Yea i'm already on spark 3.5.X, I see that that info is not included in my question - and it should be. I'm updating the question .  Question is updated showing the spark 3.5.0 version